# I cannot access my user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I go to my use profile.

I get this url: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/1342402/maazza.

It was working 3hours ago.

Comment: Was about to post the same thing. This is true for all user profiles, the `/users/` route appears to be broken on Main (but not here on Meta).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It is fixed now :/ just tested it

Comment: Yup, it is now fixed. SE has very proactive devs, we don't even have the time to report a problem now :)

Comment: Close as "cannot be reproduced"?  Or should we give it like an hour just to make sure?

Comment: Maybe the dev responsible for the fix will chime in (it usually happens, although it may not happen here given this bug's life expectancy). Let's wait 6 to 8 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bad roll out which caused the problem.  It was answered on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274579/164200) by m0sa who fixed it.

> It was a bad roll out of DB migrations + code at the same time. DB migrations happen when meta is built. So it was a case of old (pre-migration) code running against new DB schema. The issue fixed itself once everything was deployed to all servers across all tiers (meta & sites).